# Fortran runtime error: Text file busy

Tags: io, fortran

I have written a simple program to generate an output file, but every time I run it, no matter what unit number I give it, the compiler always gives the error:

```
Fortran runtime error: Text file busy
```

Here is the program:

```
program plottest
implicit none

integer :: z,k,m,j,i
double precision :: delta_Tem, deltax, deltaz, a
double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: T_n, T_g_init
double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: x
double precision, parameter :: pi = 3.141592653589793239d0
double precision, parameter :: T_hot = 300
double precision, parameter :: T_cold = 276
double precision, parameter :: D = 4 !height z (cm)
double precision, parameter :: L = 5 !length x (cm)
integer, parameter :: Nz = 9 !resolution in z
integer, parameter :: Nx = 6 !resolution in x
integer, parameter :: N = 10 !resolution in n

delta_Tem = T_hot-T_cold
deltaz = D/(Nz-1) !(cm)
deltax = L/(Nx-1) !(cm)
a = L/D

allocate(T_n(N,Nz))
allocate(T_g_init(Nx,Nz))
allocate(x(1:Nx))

z=0
T_n(1,1)=T_hot
do k=2,Nz
    T_n(1,k) = T_hot-((k-1)*delta_Tem)
end do

z=0
T_n(2,1)=0
do k=1,Nz
    do m=2,N
        T_n(m,k) = T_n(1,k)*sin(pi*(k-1)*deltaz)
    enddo
enddo

do j=1,Nx
    x(j) = x(j)+deltax
enddo

do k=1,Nz
    do j=1,Nx
        do m=1,N
            T_g_init(j,k)=T_g_init(j,k)+T_n(m,k)*cos(m*pi*x(j)/a)
        enddo
    enddo
enddo

open(unit = 15, file = "plottest")
do, i=1,n
    do, j=1,k
        write(15,"(F25.5)") T_g_init(i,j)   
        if (j==k) write(15,"(A1)") "X"
    enddo
enddo
close(15)

deallocate(T_n)
deallocate(T_g_init)
deallocate(x)

end program plottest
```

As far as I know, there are no other processes running, and no other text files open. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are defining your output file the same thing your executable is called: `plottest`. Set it to `plottest.dat` and you will have no problems.